# How to solve this error: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to

Tags: python, flutter, dart, websocket

I'm trying to create an application on flutter that connects to python server using websockets. I want to listen to messages in different functions but I always get errors. ChatGPT helped me to build this function to listen to every message -

```
void listenToMessage(Function(String) onMessageReceived) {
     final subscription = channel.stream.listen((message) {
        if(message is String) {
            onMessageReceived(message);
        } else {
            onMessageReceived(utf8.decode(message));
        }
      }, onError: (error) {
        print("Error receiving message: $error");
      });

  // Store the subscription so that it can be canceled later
      subscription.onDone(() => subscription.cancel());
}
```

and each time That I want to listen to message I call it. But, after the first time I listen to message I listen in another function and it gives me the error I've pointed out above. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem? Thank you and let me know if there is something that's not clear(my English isn't the best too).